# Error whilst attempting to generate Objects - Constructor classes

Tags: java, string, exception, int, containers

I am having issues with compiling my code.

The issues appears to be when I try to generate objects from the Customer class in my main Class. The line of code in the main class CareHire is:

```
newCust[i]=new Customer();
```

I am entering a String and Int, and numbering each entry in an array. This is the line I was planning to use for each instance, though it obviously  isn't correct and I am unsure of how to proceed.

When I edit this line out, I am to build. Clicking the 'Enter' button appears to  only displaying the string and not the int value. What should I be doing here?

Main Class: CareHire

```
package CareHire;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CareHire extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JLabel nameLabel=new JLabel("Name");
private JLabel daysLabel=new JLabel("Days of Hire");
private JTextField nameField=new JTextField(16);
    private JTextField daysField=new JTextField(11);
    private JButton enterButton=new JButton("Enter");
private JButton displayButton=new JButton("Display");
    private JButton searchButton= new JButton("Search");
    private JButton displayStatButton=new JButton("Statistics");
    private JButton exitButton=new JButton("Exit");
    private JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea(16,35);
    private Customer newCust[]=new Customer[20]; 
    int numProcessed=0;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 480;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 430;

//This is the problematic section

public CareHire() {

       super("  Care Hire System   ");
       setLayout(new FlowLayout());  

//Issues appears to be with this For Loop

       for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  {
       newCust[i]=new Customer();
    }

//End there. Remainder of code is provided for context.

       add(nameLabel);              
       add(nameField);
       add(daysLabel);
       add(daysField);

       add(enterButton);
       add(displayButton);
       add(searchButton);
       add(displayStatButton);
       add(exitButton);

       add(textArea);
       enterButton.addActionListener(this);  
       displayButton.addActionListener(this);
       searchButton.addActionListener(this);
       displayStatButton.addActionListener(this);
       exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    }
}

    public void processInput()
    {
    textArea.setText(nameField.getText());
    newCust[numProcessed].setDoH(Integer.parseInt(daysField.getText()));               
    String title="Customer   Days of Hire ($)\n\n";
    textArea.setText(title+newCust[numProcessed].getName()+ "\t $"+newCust[numProcessed].getDoH()+"\t "+" ");               
    nameField.setText("");                
    daysField.setText("");                
    numProcessed++;
}

    public void display()       {
                if(numProcessed==0) {    //no data entered             
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Need Customers","Display All",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);         
        return;       
        }    
        String allItems="";    
        for(int i=0;i<numProcessed;i++)    {     
            allItems=allItems+(i+1)+".\t"+newCust[i].getName()+ "\t\t $"+newCust[i].getDoH()+"\t "+"   "+"\n";}    

        textArea.setText("No.\t Customer \t Days of Hire \n\n"+allItems); 
    }

    public void search()
    {

    }



       public void statistics()     {

if(numProcessed==0){ //no data entered                
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Need Customers", "Find Max",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);          
return;
    }

String maxName=null;
int maxAmount=-10000;


for(int i=0;i<numProcessed;i++) {
if(newCust[i].getDoH()>maxAmount){
maxAmount=newCust[i].getDoH();
maxName=newCust[i].getName();
}
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       JFrame frame = new CareHire();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Container Class : Customer

```
 package CareHire;

public class Customer {

private String name;   
private int doh;

public Customer(String custName, int totalDays)    {       
name = custName;
doh = totalDays;
}

public void setName(String custName )  {
name = custName;
}

public String getName()   {
return name;
}

public void setDoH(int totalDays)    {
doh = totalDays;
}

public int getDoH() {
return doh;
}
}
```

Comment: `s[i]=int new custName ();` wouldn't compile either.

Comment: Please improve your title **and** add a **question**, as it stands it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to make this legible whilst investigating the issue myself. I think the problem may be that I'm not sure of what questions I should be asking. It's got me stumped. I've updated the main body with a paragraph of flailing questions.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is wrong `s[i]=String new custName ();`

it should be `s[i] = new Customer();`

"s" is declared as an array of customers `private Customer s[]=new Customer[20]`

I assume Cusotmer has a Constructor or some methods to add the Name and Days of hire data.  You would need to share more code for me to see exactly how to populate the object.